# Use Ajax in a view outside Its path

Tags: views, ajax, uri

I am using a view that I get from views_get_view('') and I put it inside a node page.
The problem is that the view normally uses AJAX (to filter,pagination,etc...) only when called through Its path.
This is not my case here because the view is calling from the node page.

Do you know how to handle this?
note that I retrieve a page view using views_get_view('MYVIEW').
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue.
Changed the type to view block and then I did [`views_embed_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7)

Works fine